# kernel 2.6.36 not booting

Tags: linux-kernel

I m a newbie to kernel programming. I am trying to boot the kernel 2.6.36 on my ECG machine.It was working perfectly on 2.6.33.2. It is getting stuck on this step:

```
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 81000000 ...
   Image Name:                                                                  
   Created:      2010-12-27   5:55:56 UTC                                       
   Image Type:   MIPS Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)                      
   Data Size:    1974278 Bytes =  1.9 MB                                        
   Load Address: 80100000                                                       
   Entry Point:  80104730                                                       
   Verifying Checksum ... OK                                                    
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK                                            

Starting kernel ...
```

After this the system either resets or it hangs. I have also checked the configuration & set it properly.Please let me know.

Comment: this should be posted in www.superuser.com

Comment: Never say that "I checked the configuration and it is correct." If it doesn't work, how can you be sure the configuration is correct?

Comment: Need more info. What arguments are you passing the kernel?